# Azure file copy Task - [error]Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-blob-storage

Within Azure DevOps I have a release pipeline that uses the Azure file copy @ version 2.154.19 to copy some files to blob storage.

Recently, the task started to fail with the following error in the logs:

```
2020-02-03T11:15:33.0304141Z ##[error]Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The full task logs from Azure DevOps are as follows

```
2020-02-03T11:15:14.5316566Z ##[section]Starting: AzureBlob File Copy
2020-02-03T11:15:14.5429010Z ==============================================================================
2020-02-03T11:15:14.5429097Z Task         : Azure file copy
2020-02-03T11:15:14.5429168Z Description  : Copy files to Azure Blob Storage or virtual machines
2020-02-03T11:15:14.5429219Z Version      : 2.154.19
2020-02-03T11:15:14.5429281Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-02-03T11:15:14.5429338Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy
2020-02-03T11:15:14.5429551Z ==============================================================================
2020-02-03T11:15:17.6071596Z ##[command]Import-Module -Name C:\Modules\azurerm_2.1.0\AzureRM\2.1.0\AzureRM.psd1 -Global
2020-02-03T11:15:29.5994320Z ##[warning]The names of some imported commands from the module 'AzureRM.Websites' include unapproved verbs that might make them less discoverable. To find the commands with unapproved verbs, run the Import-Module command again with the Verbose parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type Get-Verb.
2020-02-03T11:15:29.6177486Z ##[command]Import-Module -Name C:\Modules\azurerm_2.1.0\AzureRM.Profile\2.1.0\AzureRM.Profile.psm1 -Global
2020-02-03T11:15:30.0756632Z ##[command]Add-AzureRMAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant *** -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -EnvironmentName AzureCloud @processScope
2020-02-03T11:15:31.2123104Z ##[command] Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionId 4fc034ca-6877-4bfd-83a6-5ffe29608da5 -TenantId ***
2020-02-03T11:15:33.0304141Z ##[error]Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2020-02-03T11:15:33.0638228Z ##[section]Finishing: AzureBlob File Copy
```

The configuration for the task is as follows:
[image]

Nothing has changed recently but this task now seems to be failing.

I've set the variable `system.debug` to `true` and now I get the following logs:

```
2020-02-04T13:12:06.4274088Z ##[debug]Validating minimum required azure powershell version is greater than or equal to 0.9.0
2020-02-04T13:12:06.4332040Z ##[debug]Populating RepositorySourceLocation property for module AzureRM.
2020-02-04T13:12:06.4360442Z ##[debug]Loading module from path 'C:\Modules\azurerm_2.1.0\AzureRM\2.1.0\AzureRM.psm1'.
2020-02-04T13:12:06.4556756Z ##[debug]Installed Azure PowerShell version: 2.1.0
2020-02-04T13:12:06.4579801Z ##[debug]Compare azure versions: 2.1.0, 0.9.0
2020-02-04T13:12:06.4599735Z ##[debug]Validated the required azure powershell version is greater than or equal to 0.9.0
2020-02-04T13:12:06.4685961Z ##[debug][Azure Call]Getting resource details for azure storage account resource: xxx221 with resource type: Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts
2020-02-04T13:12:07.0852040Z ##[debug]System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2020-02-04T13:12:07.0865383Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.Models.PSStorageAccount..ctor(StorageAccount storageAccount) in d:\workspace\powershell-sign\src\ResourceManager\Storage\Commands.Management.Storage\Models\PSStorageAccount.cs:line 27
2020-02-04T13:12:07.0880480Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.Models.PSStorageAccount.Create(StorageAccount storageAccount, IStorageManagementClient client) in d:\workspace\powershell-sign\src\ResourceManager\Storage\Commands.Management.Storage\Models\PSStorageAccount.cs:line 87
2020-02-04T13:12:07.0894045Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.StorageAccountBaseCmdlet.<>c__DisplayClass2.<WriteStorageAccountList>b__1(StorageAccount storageAccount) in d:\workspace\powershell-sign\src\ResourceManager\Storage\Commands.Management.Storage\StorageAccount\StorageAccountBaseCmdlet.cs:line 161
2020-02-04T13:12:07.0908039Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.GeneralUtilities.ForEach[T](IEnumerable`1 sequence, Action`1 action) in d:\workspace\powershell-sign\src\Common\Commands.Common\GeneralUtilities.cs:line 147
2020-02-04T13:12:07.0923496Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.StorageAccountBaseCmdlet.WriteStorageAccountList(IEnumerable`1 storageAccounts) in d:\workspace\powershell-sign\src\ResourceManager\Storage\Commands.Management.Storage\StorageAccount\StorageAccountBaseCmdlet.cs:line 161
2020-02-04T13:12:07.0938702Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.ProcessRecord() in d:\workspace\powershell-sign\src\Common\Commands.Common\AzurePSCmdlet.cs:line 610
2020-02-04T13:12:07.1882171Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;code={"Task_Internal_Error":"TemporaryCopyingToBlobContainerFailed"};]
2020-02-04T13:12:07.1928893Z ##[debug]Trying to disconnect from Azure and clear context at process scope
2020-02-04T13:12:07.4018399Z ##[debug]Caught exception from task script.
2020-02-04T13:12:07.4054453Z ##[debug]Error record:
2020-02-04T13:12:07.4764182Z ##[debug]Get-AzureRmStorageAccount : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2020-02-04T13:12:07.4779906Z ##[debug]At D:\a\_tasks\AzureFileCopy_eb72cb01-a7e5-427b-a8a1-1b31ccac8a43\2.154.19\AzureUtilityGTE1.0.ps1:27 char:47
2020-02-04T13:12:07.4795063Z ##[debug]+ ... ResourceDetails = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ErrorAction Stop | Where ...
2020-02-04T13:12:07.4809226Z ##[debug]+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-02-04T13:12:07.4822827Z ##[debug]    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureRmStorageAccount], NullReferenceException
2020-02-04T13:12:07.4836831Z ##[debug]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.GetAzureStorageAccountCommand
2020-02-04T13:12:07.4851249Z ##[debug] 
2020-02-04T13:12:07.4876156Z ##[debug]Script stack trace:
2020-02-04T13:12:07.4914114Z ##[debug]at Get-AzureStorageAccountResourceGroupName, D:\a\_tasks\AzureFileCopy_eb72cb01-a7e5-427b-a8a1-1b31ccac8a43\2.154.19\AzureUtilityGTE1.0.ps1: line 27
2020-02-04T13:12:07.4926798Z ##[debug]at Get-AzureStorageKeyFromARM, D:\a\_tasks\AzureFileCopy_eb72cb01-a7e5-427b-a8a1-1b31ccac8a43\2.154.19\AzureUtilityRest.ps1: line 28
2020-02-04T13:12:07.4942375Z ##[debug]at Get-StorageKey, D:\a\_tasks\AzureFileCopy_eb72cb01-a7e5-427b-a8a1-1b31ccac8a43\2.154.19\Utility.ps1: line 149
2020-02-04T13:12:07.4955473Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, D:\a\_tasks\AzureFileCopy_eb72cb01-a7e5-427b-a8a1-1b31ccac8a43\2.154.19\AzureFileCopy.ps1: line 101
2020-02-04T13:12:07.4968797Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
2020-02-04T13:12:07.4982585Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 22
2020-02-04T13:12:07.4996709Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 18
2020-02-04T13:12:07.5010393Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
2020-02-04T13:12:07.5033417Z ##[debug]Exception:
2020-02-04T13:12:07.5059409Z ##[debug]System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2020-02-04T13:12:07.5073947Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.Models.PSStorageAccount..ctor(StorageAccount storageAccount) in d:\workspace\powershell-sign\src\ResourceManager\Storage\Commands.Management.Storage\Models\PSStorageAccount.cs:line 27
2020-02-04T13:12:07.5086710Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.Models.PSStorageAccount.Create(StorageAccount storageAccount, IStorageManagementClient client) in d:\workspace\powershell-sign\src\ResourceManager\Storage\Commands.Management.Storage\Models\PSStorageAccount.cs:line 87
2020-02-04T13:12:07.5104212Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.StorageAccountBaseCmdlet.<>c__DisplayClass2.<WriteStorageAccountList>b__1(StorageAccount storageAccount) in d:\workspace\powershell-sign\src\ResourceManager\Storage\Commands.Management.Storage\StorageAccount\StorageAccountBaseCmdlet.cs:line 161
2020-02-04T13:12:07.5119770Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.GeneralUtilities.ForEach[T](IEnumerable`1 sequence, Action`1 action) in d:\workspace\powershell-sign\src\Common\Commands.Common\GeneralUtilities.cs:line 147
2020-02-04T13:12:07.5133721Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.StorageAccountBaseCmdlet.WriteStorageAccountList(IEnumerable`1 storageAccounts) in d:\workspace\powershell-sign\src\ResourceManager\Storage\Commands.Management.Storage\StorageAccount\StorageAccountBaseCmdlet.cs:line 161
2020-02-04T13:12:07.5148324Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.ProcessRecord() in d:\workspace\powershell-sign\src\Common\Commands.Common\AzurePSCmdlet.cs:line 610
2020-02-04T13:12:07.5213129Z ##[error]Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2020-02-04T13:12:07.5213434Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2020-02-04T13:12:07.5222027Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed]
2020-02-04T13:12:07.5808798Z ##[section]Finishing: AzureBlob File Copy
```

Is there any better debugging that I can enable for Azure DevOps tasks?

Comment: Tested and cannot reproduce the issue, just encounter the issue https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9922, but can copy files to blob storage successfully. Whatever, please try the preview version (3.*) and check if that works, both of them are working for me.

Comment: Just tried the preview version (3.x) and that fails in the same way. I also tried the 1.x version but that won't work use to validation issues on the container name containing `$`.

Comment: Tested again but still cannot reproduce the issue. Please try to create a new storage account and try it again to check if that works.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT just created another storage account and tried to copy to that one instead and it gets the same error.

Comment: To note, the same service connection to the azure subscription is being used to swap containers.

Comment: Just noticed that it shows `version 2.154.16` on my side when using version (2.*), but not `version 2.154.19`, not sure if it is related to this issue. Do you have other organizations, do they have the same issue?

Comment: I've not got a similar setup in another organization. 

Comment: Well, whatever this issue is reported in Github : https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/12154, let's waiting for the product team's response.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Kevin if you want to get debug information in a release definition create a variable `system.debug` and set it to `true`. I just took a look at [github](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/12154) and there is an open issue with the same error message for the v2 version of the task.

I would run it with debug, to see if its the same issue and then try the v3 version of the task.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question. Looks like it's failing getting resource details.

Comment: Saw what else you tried above. I wonder if there is an issue with the service connection used in the pipeline. Are you using it anywhere else? Or an issue with the storage account like Andy mentioned. As a workaround for ```$``` and the v1 version of the task you might be able to single quote it in the input field ```'$web'```